# Transparency with polygon command

Tags: r, polygon

I used the `polygon` command in R which created an area in the plot. However, the values in this area are not shown whereas the main aim is to monitor these values. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: Helps if you include a bit of code to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use The function `rgb()` to specify a color with an alpha transparency.

for example :

```
xx <- c(1:50)
 yy <- rnorm(50)
 n <- 50
 hline <- 0
plot (yy ~ xx, type="n", axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
text(x=xx,y=min(yy)+max(yy),labels='a')
polygon(c(xx[1], xx, xx[n]), c(min(yy), yy, min(yy)),    
        col=rgb(1, 0, 0,0.5), border=NA)
```

[image]

Comment: another convenient possibility is something like `adjustcolor("red",alpha.f=0.5)`

Comment: @BenBolker, this should be an answer!

Answer (score 13):

Another convenient possibility for making a lighter/more-transparent version of an existing color is to use `adjustcolor()`, something like

```
adjustcolor("red", alpha.f=0.5)
```